# How can I pass in the contribution amount via URL?

Tags: contributions, price-sets

Is there a quick way to pass in the contribution amount via URL on custom amounts?

```
http://example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2&price=35
```

I'm not looking to use a price set, just a total amount. Ideally, I'd like to pay an existing contribution and bring up a form with the amount and contribution to pay against with a credit card.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this on CiviCRM 4.6.18 and successfully passed the amount through using the field Name or id (inspect the field to find the name or id)
In the case of my form I did this:
http://example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2&price_5=35

Comment: This is still working on civicrm 5.x.x

Answer (score 3):

If a javascript solution suits you:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = document.location;
var amount = a.search.match(/amount=([0-9]+)/)[1];
jQuery('#search input[name="q"]').val(amount);
```

- Visit [this URL](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/pass-in-contribution-amount-via-url?amount=1234) -- current page + `?amount=1234`
- Paste the above code in your browser console
- Observe that the StackExchange search box now contains the value from the current page's query params.
- Add a free-text amount input to your contribute form.
- Use equivalent approach to populate that value on your own site.

Comment: [1](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Update+custom+fields+in+contributions+and+events+by+passing+variables+in+a+URL), [2](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,34966.msg148876.html#msg148876). The first two lines look weird, but they are just there to allow the third to easily steal the query param from the current URL.

Comment: Thanks for the solution .It would be great to have a CiviCRM generated form, ideally attached to the Contribution ID. The idea is to apply a payment using the CiviCRM payment processor to an existing contribution. I was hoping I could use an existing contribution form and pipe the contribution ID and amount in.

Comment: The solution above is intended for that use case. If you need it in the page instead of via JS, you want `hook_buildform()` in a custom extension I think.

Comment: Thanks. Did you have an example to get started?

Comment: The civi tracker module linked in the wiki article on [this comment](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/how-can-i-pass-in-the-contribution-amount-via-url/4901#comment4218_4901) is an example with similar functionality if you join the dots.

Comment: Thanks @Chris-Burgess. Will take a look. The link text in your last commend appears to point to this same post?

Comment: Yes, it's pointing to the comment with links 1, 2 above it, one of which is a reference to existing documentation on the CiviCRM Wiki.