# What's the right way override the default source on a contribution page?

Tags: civicontribute

If I add this to the inbound link: https://mysite.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&**source=facebookcampaign123**

Will my source addendum be added to the contribution record?

Comment: did you test this? what was the outcome?

Comment: it did not work. as Cheis Burgess notes below, this can be done with JavaScript- but only if it fills a different custom field.

Comment: You can add 'campaign' as a profile used for Contributions. So i don't think you need a custom field per se. Just the js solution chris suggests.

Comment: yeah- sadly I'm already using "campaign" for a higher level of organization. for example, a fundraising campaign (let's call it End of Year Giving) might share the same mailing list of targets but have at least three four inbound sources: direct mail response, one of several emails in a series, a Facebook campaign and a radio promotion. tracking everything is probably impossible, but it's important for me to know if a gift resulted from email #1, 2 or 3... or from some other online source.

Answer (score 1):

One of our clients has done something similar to this answer:

- [How can I pass in the contribution amount via URL?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/how-can-i-pass-in-the-contribution-amount-via-url/4901)

but using a campaign selector or a custom field on the contribution page. Not sure from memory whether they did it with JS or Smarty, but the end result was an invisible field which tracked this.